# Why is my packet reading program returning incorrect data?

Tags: c, linux, libpcap

I have written a packet reader that uses libpcap to read a capture file. It reads the capture file and uploads captured data to a MySQL database. Sometimes it seems to work fine and others it returns invalid data (e.g. the source and destination ip will be the same, the tcp ports are all junk). I'm running this under a virtual RHEL 5. Here is my code (sorry if it's rather long or unnecessarily convoluted, this is my first attempt at this).

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <net/ethernet.h>

#include <netinet/ether.h>
#include <netinet/if_ether.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>

#include "npc_tcp.h"
#include "npc_udp.h"

#include <ftw.h>
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

const int IPTYPE_TCP = 6;
const int IPTYPE_UDP = 17;

struct cap_data {
  char ts[64];
  u_int16_t ether_type;
  u_int16_t proto;
  char *srcip;
  char *dstip;
  char *srcmac;
  u_int16_t srcport;
  u_int16_t dstport;
  u_int8_t flags;
  u_int capsize;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  //pcap
  struct cap_data data;
  struct pcap_pkthdr pkthdr;
  const u_char *packet;
  pcap_t *handle;
  char *fname = argv[1];
  printf("%s\n", fname);
  char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE]; 
  handle = pcap_open_offline(fname, errbuf);
  char buf[1000];

  while (packet = pcap_next(handle, &pkthdr)) {

    int ether_flag;
    struct ether_header *ether;    
    u_short ether_type;           

    ether = (struct ether_header *) packet;
    data.ether_type = ntohs(ether->ether_type);

    ether_flag = 1;

    if (ether_flag) {
      if (data.ether_type == ETHERTYPE_IP) {
        struct ip *ip_hdr;
        u_int length = pkthdr.len;

        ip_hdr = (struct ip *)(packet + sizeof(struct ether_header));

      data.proto = ip_hdr->ip_p;
      data.dstip = inet_ntoa(ip_hdr->ip_dst);
      data.srcip = inet_ntoa(ip_hdr->ip_src);

      if (data.proto == IPTYPE_TCP) {
        struct tcphdr *tcp;
        tcp = (struct tcphdr*)(packet + sizeof(struct ether_header) + 
                sizeof(struct ip));

        data.srcport = tcp->th_sport;
        data.dstport = tcp->th_dport;

        printf("%s %u   %s %u\n\n", inet_ntoa(ip_hdr->ip_src), tcp->th_sport, inet_ntoa(ip_hdr->ip_dst), tcp->th_dport);

      } else if (data.proto == IPTYPE_UDP) {
        struct udphdr *udp;
        udp = (struct udphdr *)(packet + sizeof(struct ether_header) + 
                sizeof(struct ip));
        data.srcport = udp->uh_sport;
        data.dstport = udp->uh_dport;

        printf("%s %u   %s %u\n\n", inet_ntoa(ip_hdr->ip_src), udp->uh_sport, inet_ntoa(ip_hdr->ip_dst), udp->uh_dport);

        }
      }
    }
  }//while

  pcap_close(handle);

  return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

This outputs..

```
source ip      port   dest ip       port

66.68.236.207 30151     66.68.236.207 47873

172.22.162.235 60920    172.22.162.235 36175

67.207.28.150 23007     67.207.28.150 22038

172.22.162.235 60920    172.22.162.235 36175

67.207.28.151 22038     67.207.28.151 23007

65.55.87.43 20480       65.55.87.43 21764

67.207.28.150 23007     67.207.28.150 22038
```

The addresses should not be the same and the port numbers are wrong as well.

I have no idea where to even start looking for errors as my code (at least to me) looks correct. Any help, tips, or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Sure thing. Will post an update ASAP. However, I'm just about to leave my office for the day so that will probably have to wait till tomorrow sorry.

Comment: Can you try to make a shorter program that gives the same problem? See http://sscce.org.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the capture file in Wireshark, and seeing what type of packets are present at the point where your program goes wrong?  Probably some other packet format is there which you aren't handling correctly.

Comment: There is not one point in runtime where the program starts to output incorrect data. Once executed the program is either going to run perfect, or just start outputting wrong results. It seems to only affect IP addresses and ports mainly showing the destination and source to be the same. The timestamp, mac address, and other fields are fine. And yes, I've compared the results with Wireshark's that is why I am certain the fields are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. inet_ntoa returns a pointer to a static buffer.
   When calling it twice within the same printf, it overwrites the same buffer. So you end up printing the same data.
   Use inet_ntop instead, and give each call a separate buffer.
2. You should use ntohs() to convert the ports to host-order before printing.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to accept your answer. I had actually solved this a while back on my own and forgot to update this question.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if, right after calling `pcap_open_offline()`, you do

```
if (pcap_datalink(handle) != DLT_EN10MB) {
  fprintf(stderr, "This program handles only Ethernet captures\n");
  return 2;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to explain the problem. He says he's getting invalid data, not an error message. You're right that limiting the program to 10Mbps Ethernet makes no sense.

Comment: Take back my previous comment. I misunderstood the intention.

Comment: Actually, DLT_EN10MB's name is historical - it's for *all* Ethernet speeds, not jut 10MB/s Ethernet.  The program as he wrote it is already limited to Ethernet, because it assumes every packet begins with an Ethernet header; that check is to make sure the program fails if it's handed a file where packets *don't* have an Ethernet header, rather than misdissecting those packets.

Comment: And, yes, the two problems you mention are additional problems with the program, which won't prevent it from getting the right fields, but will prevent it from *ever* printing the IP addresses correctly under any circumstances and from *ever* printing the port numbers correctly if the program is running on a little-endian machine (such as anything with an x86 or x86-64 processor, on which it's probably running).